# Python flask parsing JSON content from output

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, parsing

I have an output that contains system output information from a remote server, and at the very end of the output, it contains a JSON object. Like this:

output:

```
...
-Verification-
-Test1: PASS
-Test2: PASS
...
...
Result: PASS
...
#JSON Object below
{"path": "/my/path/file.log",  "name": "Roger", "year": 2018}
```

The output would only contain one set of `{}` and that is the JSON object I want to parse. So we don't have to worry about grabbing wrong information

I would like my flask app to parse this output to only return the JSON object (everything in the `{}` including the `{}`) and filter all the text above it. How can I do this?

Comment: Did you tried using `regex` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re
jsonstr='''...
-Verification-
-Test1: PASS
-Test2: PASS
...
...
Result: PASS
...
#JSON Object below
{"path": "/my/path/file.log",  "name": "Roger", "year": 2018}'''
print(jsonstr.lstrip(re.sub('{.*}','',jsonstr)))
```

---

```
jsonstr='''...
-Verification-
-Test1: PASS
-Test2: PASS
...
...
Result: PASS
...
#JSON Object below
{"path": "/my/path/file.log",  "name": "Roger", "year": 2018}'''
print([i for i in jsonstr.splitlines() if i.startswith('{') and i.endswith('}')])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regex (`re`) with expression `{.*}`

Answer (score 0):

To locate the JSON string, since you know there are no other '{'s in it, use `str.find` and string indexing:

```
json_loc = jsonstr.find('{')
if json_loc >= 0:
    jsonstr = jsonstr[json_loc:]
else:
    raise Exception("no JSON string found")
```